# Updating only the first object in NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, nsmanagedobject

I want to update the first record in the `NSManagedObject`. What I have here updates all of them which I realise is because I am selecting them all and updating them all using the **for** but how do I just update the first record?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];
NSError *errorLoading = nil;
self.users = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestNext error:& errorLoading];
for (NSManagedObject *usersObject in [self users])
{
   [usersObject setValue:@"*" forKey:@"currentUser"];
}
NSError *error;
[context save:&error3];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kind of like this:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];
fetchRequest.fetchLimit = 1; //Fetch only one object (optional)

NSError *errorLoading = nil;
NSManagedObject *user = [[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestNext error:& errorLoading] firstObject];
if (errorLoading) {
    //handle error
}
[user setValue:@"*" forKey:@"currentUser"];
NSError *error = nil;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    //handle error
}
```

First of all, if you only need one object, you can set the `fetchLimit` to 1. It is not required, it's just a small optimization (it will make CoreData stop after fetching the first object). Then you execute the request just like you normally would and get the first object from the resulting array.

Comment: Perfect. The fetchLimit is a new one on me. Thanks a million.

Answer (score 2):

From the results (array) you simply select the one at index:0

```
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestNext error:& errorLoading];

if (results.count>0) {
    NSManagedObject *userObject = results[0];
    [usersObject setValue:@"*" forKey:@"currentUser"];
}
NSError *saveError = nil;
[context save:&saveError];
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the method firstObject defined in NSArray.

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Users"];
NSError *errorLoading = nil;
NSArray *users = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestNext error:& errorLoading];

NSManagedObject *singleUser = [users firstObject];
if(singleUser){
    [singleUser setValue:@"*" forKey:@"currentUser"];
}

NSError *error;
if([context save:&error]){

}
```